# How can I stop my NavMesh from baking inside static game objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

In my scene I have 2 cubes with navigation static checked in the inspector and the navmesh has been baked.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9qXQ.png
You can see in this screenshot how when I put the camera inside the top cube, the navmesh has been baked underneath it, even though the cubes are perfectly aligned. I'm trying to avoid putting a navigation block under every static in the scene that has walkable areas above it. Is it not possible to have navmeshed surfaces that exclude the area underneath if it is unreachable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that if you do not have any links between the NavMeshArea you can just leave it like that, as the NavMeshAgents respect the area they are spawn/move to. But if you really want to get rid of it see below.

One thing you could do, is to add a [NavMeshObstacle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshObstacle.html) to the object and resize it, so that it fits the top area you want to get rid of. This would remove the area inside the cube.

Note that this is a workaround, as there is very likely another and better solution to the problem, but this solves the issue you are having very quickly.